# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4BB' to data type int

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Here is all the code.  I get conversion failed converting varchar to data type int and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have a table with one row and one field varchar(4) called SequenceAlphaNum

This is the script for the table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SequenceAlphaNum](
    [AlphaNum] [varchar](4) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

The Data in that one cell table is

### 4BA

I have created a stored procedure algorithm to break apart the '4BA' into ACSII and increment the necessary character and then piece the characters back together again into a variable @SequenceAlphaNumOut varchar(4)

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSequenceAlphaNum] 

AS
DECLARE 
 @SequenceAlphaNumOut  varchar(4) 
,@asciiAlphaStart INT= 65
,@asciiAlphaEnd int = 90

,@asciiNumericStart INT= 49
,@asciiNewmaericEnd int = 57

,@SequenceAlphaNum as varchar(3)

,@FirstCharDec as int
,@SecondCharDec as int
,@ThirdCharDec as int


,@FirstChar as varchar(1)
,@SecondChar as  varchar(1)
,@ThirdChar as  varchar(1)

set @SequenceAlphaNum = (SELECT  AlphaNum
FROM            SequenceAlphaNum)


set @FirstCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,1, 1)))
set @SecondCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,2, 1)))
set @ThirdCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,3, 1)))

if @ThirdCharDec < @asciiAlphaEnd
    begin
    set @ThirdCharDec = @ThirdCharDec+1
    End
Else
IF @ThirdCharDec = @asciiAlphaEnd
    begin
    set @ThirdCharDec = @asciiAlphaStart

        if @SecondCharDec < @asciiAlphaEnd 
            begin
                set @SecondCharDec = @SecondCharDec+1
            end
        else
        IF @SecondCharDec = @asciiAlphaEnd
            begin 
            set @SecondCharDec = @asciiAlphaStart
            set @FirstCharDec = @FirstCharDec + 1

            end

end




set @SequenceAlphaNumOut = (Select CAST(char(@FirstCharDec) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(char(@SecondCharDec) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(char(@ThirdCharDec) AS VARCHAR(1)) )

 Update SequenceAlphaNum
 set AlphaNum = @SequenceAlphaNumOut
 Where AlphaNum = @SequenceAlphaNum

return  @SequenceAlphaNumOut
```

The problem is when I run the Stored Procedure

```
DECLARE  @SequenceAlphaNumOut  varchar(4) 
EXEC @SequenceAlphaNumOut = [dbo].[spSequenceAlphaNum] 
Select @SequenceAlphaNumOut
```

I get this error and I can't figure out how to fix it

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spSequenceAlphaNum, Line 67
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4BB' to data type int.

Comment: The stored procedure does an update on a table so I am not able to make it a stored function. I created an output parameter. Moved this variable up and made it an output parameter and I get the same error. @SequenceAlphaNumOut varchar(4) output AS DECLARE

Answer (score 3):

Stored procedures should not be used to return values.  They do return a status and that status is *always* an integer.

So, this is your problem:

```
return  @SequenceAlphaNumOut
```

Two options to fix this:

1. Change the stored procedure to a stored function that returns a string.
2. Add an output parameter to the stored procedure to pass the value back.

Comment: The stored procedure does an update on a table so I am not able to make it a stored function.  I created an output parameter.  Moved this variable up and made it an output parameter and I get the same error.  
 @SequenceAlphaNumOut  varchar(4) output
AS
DECLARE

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer this will work and return the correct Alpha numeric number.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSequenceAlphaNum] 

 @SequenceAlphaNumOut  varchar(4) output
AS
DECLARE 

@asciiAlphaStart INT= 65
,@asciiAlphaEnd int = 90

,@asciiNumericStart INT= 49
,@asciiNewmaericEnd int = 57

,@SequenceAlphaNum as varchar(3)

,@FirstCharDec as int
,@SecondCharDec as int
,@ThirdCharDec as int


,@FirstChar as varchar(1)
,@SecondChar as  varchar(1)
,@ThirdChar as  varchar(1)

set @SequenceAlphaNum = (SELECT  AlphaNum
FROM            SequenceAlphaNum)


set @FirstCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,1, 1)))
set @SecondCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,2, 1)))
set @ThirdCharDec = ( select ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SequenceAlphaNum,3, 1)))

if @ThirdCharDec < @asciiAlphaEnd
   begin
    set @ThirdCharDec = @ThirdCharDec+1
   End
Else
  IF @ThirdCharDec = @asciiAlphaEnd
      begin
    set @ThirdCharDec = @asciiAlphaStart

        if @SecondCharDec < @asciiAlphaEnd 
            begin
                set @SecondCharDec = @SecondCharDec+1
            end
        else
        IF @SecondCharDec = @asciiAlphaEnd
            begin 
            set @SecondCharDec = @asciiAlphaStart
            set @FirstCharDec = @FirstCharDec + 1

            end

end


set @SequenceAlphaNumOut = (Select CAST(char(@FirstCharDec) AS VARCHAR(1)) +
    CAST(char(@SecondCharDec) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(char(@ThirdCharDec) AS  
    VARCHAR(1)) )

Update SequenceAlphaNum
 set AlphaNum = @SequenceAlphaNumOut
 Where AlphaNum = @SequenceAlphaNum

return
```